# Treeview Tkinter : Is it possible to add a background color to a specific column and a specific cell?

Tags: tkinter, treeview, background-color

I am trying to make a GUI App with the treeview widget.
The problem is that i dont find the way to add a bg color to a specific column.
Same for a cell, is it possible to colorize a specific cell depending of the value ?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to colorize a specific cell in the treeview widget.